# Find a way to prevent parcel from changing media query syntax

Tags: sass, media-queries, parcel

I'm trying to build a website using Html, Sass, and JavaScript. So I'm using parcel to bundle my website but the problem I've come up with is that if I want to start bundling by typing "npm start" in command line, parcel change the media query syntax from

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    div {
        background-color: teal;
    }
}
```

to

```
@media screen and (width <= 600px) {
  div {
    background-color: teal;
  }
}
```

But the problem with this last syntax is that it doesn't work in older browsers in fact I think it's a new media query syntax and it's not widely supported at the moment.

So I hope to get help and find a solution to this problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use browserslist to fix it: https://browsersl.ist/

Just add the following line in your **package.json** (root level)

```
"browserslist": "> 0.5%, last 3 versions, not dead"
```

*Note: you can play with the configuration for your needs.*

Answer (score 0):

i tried to follow suggested solution by adding browserslist, but doesn't make any difference.
After running build for scss:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {...}
```

I get again  following css:

```
@media only screen and (width >= 768px) {...}
```

which is ignored by example Safari 13.1

also tried a even more specific browserslist configuration, but without no success :( ...

```
"browserslist": "> 0.5%, last 3 versions, not dead, Safari > 12",
```

Comment: I have this exact issue - were you able to get it working on Safari?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by setting browserlist to defaults like so,

```json
"browserslist": [
    "defaults"
  ]
```